# Вывод 2d массива в одном цикле for

Tags: java, массивы, for

Как вывести 2d массив в java, используя только **один** цикл for?

Пытался найти ответы, но нашел только решения с использованием нескольких циклов.

Пример массива:

```
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8},
    {9}
};
```

Пример вывода (формат не имеет значения):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

С одним циклом for, а не с вложенными.

---

Так что **не** что-то вроде этого:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну методика стандартная - вынести счетчики за пределы цикла и организовать логику их изменения внутри тела цикла. Лучше конечно использовать `while`, ну если нужен именно `for`, тогда могу предложить такой вариант

```java
int internalIndex = 0, extIndex = 0;
for (; extIndex < array.length; ) {
    if (internalIndex < array[extIndex].length) {
        System.out.println(array[extIndex][internalIndex++]);
    } else {
        extIndex++;
        internalIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```java
int array[][] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8},
        {9}
};

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
}
```

Не забудьте подключить: `import java.util.Arrays;`

Результат программы:

```
[1, 2, 3][4, 5][6, 7, 8][9]
```

Или если без всяких дополнений и так, как у вас в примере, то вот пример кода с комментариями:

```java
int array[][] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8},
        {9}
};

//Индекс массива в матрице, индекс элемента в массиве с индексом arrIndex
int arrIndex = 0, elIndex = 0;
//Пока мы не прошлись по всем массивам в матрице
while (arrIndex < array.length) {
    //Если elIndex < длины рассматриваемого массива, то выводим элемент
    if (elIndex < array[arrIndex].length) {
        System.out.print(array[arrIndex][elIndex]);
        //Эта проверка просто чтобы в конце не было 8, 9, :)
        if (arrIndex != array.length -1 || elIndex != array[arrIndex].length -1)
            System.out.print(", ");
        elIndex++;
    }
    //Иначе переходим к следующему массиву в матрице
    //и сбрасываем индекс элемента на 0
    else {
        arrIndex++;
        elIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Результат программы:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: Интересно конечно получается :) Для новеньких, нажимая на стрелочку вниз (голосуя против), вы подтверждаете, что "ответ не является полезным"